# how can generate random string in arm

Tags: json, string, random, arm, devops

I can't generate random string in arm

I have searched on chatgpt and i found this

```
; Initialize the LCG
        LDR r0, =seed    ; Load the seed value into r0
        MOV r1, #1103515245
        MOV r2, #12345

; Generate the random string
        MOV r3, #0       ; Initialize the string index to 0
loop:
        LDR r4, =string  ; Load the address of the string into r4
        ADD r4, r4, r3   ; Add the string index to the address
        LDR r5, [r4]     ; Load the current character from the string
        ADD r0, r0, r1   ; Update the LCG seed
        ADD r0, r0, r2
        MOV r6, #256     ; Compute 256 (the number of possible characters)
        UMULL r7, r8, r0, r6
        MOV r5, r8       ; Compute the remainder of the division by 256
        STRB r5, [r4]    ; Store the random character in the string
        ADD r3, r3, #1   ; Increment the string index
        CMP r3, #length  ; Compare the string index with the desired length
        BNE loop         ; Loop if the index is less than the length
```

how can i use this in my template
an arm code that can generate random string

Comment: you seem to be mixing high level concepts (i.e. devops, JSON and strings) with low level ones (i.e. arm, assembly code).  could you edit the question to explain more what you're trying to do?  e.g. what do you mean "template", why you are using such low level code to accomplish this task, etc.